# Occasional Slow Connection to Overseas VPS

Tags: linux, networking, vps

I apologize if this is a poor description of my problem - if there's more information that I can provide which would be helpful please tell me.

I am in the US, and I have a lower-end vps in Europe that I run keep my website, email, apps, and backups on. The load on it is generally pretty light and I'm never running low on system resources. Occasionally, however, I have issues transmitting files to and from the server. I have not been able to see any rhyme or reason to this, just that it happens.

I've done some testing: At times when I see slow connection speeds (~40k/s), friends of mine in geographically different areas (several states away) are able to connect and download files at fast speeds (4-10mb/s), which is what I am normally able to see. The opposite is sometimes true - I'll send a link to a file I've shared and others will get abysmally slow speeds.

When getting poor speeds, running an mtr to the server (or from the server) shows ~10% packet loss on a few nodes. I'm not sure how much this may have to do with the issue, but it does exist.

Where should I start to establish and test what problem I am actually having?

Comment: 1) What ping time does mtr report to your server when this happens? 2) Does the packet loss continue onwards to all further nodes? If not, then most likely it is not actual packet loss but ICMP response rate-limiting. 3) What operator is your VPS hosted at?

Comment: (1) Ping to the server is worst 110, best 93.5, avg 97.2. (2) The loss is zero for the first several nodes, then continues across the last 6 - although the % loss goes up and down a bit (ending at 5%). (3) My host is Online.net